# AdMob House Ad Issue

Tags: admob, adwhirl

Previously we have used AdWhirl, where it was simple and easy to create your House Ads. You would then quite simply adjust the settings so they were 100% or split it with AdMob or iAd.

Since AdWhirl is now shutting down it recommended to switch to AdMob which we duly did!

I have got 4 published Apps and we are transferring them onto AdMob as obviously AdWhirl ceases to remain shortly (Most disappointed). The Apps contain 2 ad bars 1 and the top and 1 at the bottom simple really. The top ad is to display house ads as we use this to showcase specific deals/events etc that are relevant to that app for the users. The bottom ad is for a revenue stream and consists of iAds/AdMob and House Ads.

All we require is a idiots guide to enable us to create these house ads as currently it purely only displays AdMob Ads.

Oh another thing can the idiots guide be for both the Old AdMob and the New AdMob too as at present im getting to my wits end with it all.